# Return Slice, Channel or Custom Iterator from DB Repository?

Tags: go

What would be the idiomatic way to design database repository for Go ?

I am using Couchbase cbgo to fetch the items which returns a reader where. I get each item one by one.

I do not want to return this abstraction to the end user of my lib.

So what would be the best way to do this ?

I could just iterate over the items and append them to a Slice.

Or, I could return a Channel, and then push each row to the channel so that the client can for range over it.

Or I could make my own iterator abstraction.

What do others do in this kind of scenarios ?

I don't really need to have the result as a slice as the data is just piped to other modules.

Comment: To the editor: it doesn't really seem better with more space

Comment: A problem is that there's no generics in go. So if your API are typed, you might want to use channels or slices in order to retain the type.

Comment: Roger i would definitely suggest you Channels because as per your requirement you need somewhat like streamed feed where you didn't expect slice, in this case channels would b the best way because you are saved from creating your own custom Iterator which otherwise would be implemented in the same way.

Comment: I ended up using a callback instead, that way, I can use all of the above solutions if I want to, just pass different callbacks..

Comment: Just build an iterator. These are nicer IMO because you don't have to spin up a goroutine (i.e., you don't have to worry about race conditions, deadlocks, etc) and they're still very easy to implement. If you want concurrency/parallelism, you can always wrap the iterator in a goroutine later.

Answer (score 0):

Maps

I learned it more [here](https://manuel.kiessling.net/2012/09/28/applying-the-clean-architecture-to-go-applications/).

- First, generate a struct with db handlers.
- Second, make interfaces matching dbhandler methods.
- Third, specify the custom interface as the key of the map.

Now, regardless of the Model struct you should be able to use db handler's methods

```golang
dbHandler := infrastructure.NewSqliteHandler("/var/tmp/production.sqlite")

handlers := make(map[string] interfaces.DbHandler)
handlers["DbUserRepo"] = dbHandler
handlers["DbCustomerRepo"] = dbHandler
handlers["DbItemRepo"] = dbHandler
handlers["DbOrderRepo"] = dbHandler
```